# How to display "Prefix" from user contact details in Audience Manager address book, on the newsletter that is sent to user?

Tags: 2013, outbound-email, audience-manager

I need to display "Prefix" from user contact details in Audience Manager address book, on the newsletter that is sent to user

I checked and found that the values for the name and surname are being displayed in the email sent using the below syntax:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="newsletter_selected_name=='FirstName' || newsletter_selected_name=='' " -->
[* Name *]
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->

<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="newsletter_selected_name=='LastName'" -->
[* Surname *]
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

However, if we are using the same for prefix, it is not displaying:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="prefix=='Prefix" -->
[* Prefix *]
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

I am not sure where to look for this. Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

I have a Prefix field in my Newsletter Body Component:
[image]

this is supposed to take the prefix value from the contact details, like the FirstName, LastName fields.

But it does not work for Prefix, even though I have values for Prefix in contact details:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[* Prefix *] is correct (assuming you've kept the default field). If it's not working, perhaps the problem is with the condition on the TemplateBeginIf?

Also, make sure you are testing it with Contacts that actually have a Prefix entered.

Comment: I have update my question with more details. The templatebegin condition is correct I think. But, maybe I am missing some other config, which I am not aware of. Please could you suggest where should I check?

Comment: If you are Testing the Mailing and use a Contact that has this field set, as you show, there is nothing else needed. The variable will be replaced by the Mailer service when it sends the test mails. Please try it without the TemplateBeginIf first, though. I'm fairly certain that is the problem.

Comment: Many Thanks..!!! that indeed was causing issues. But one query, would it not throw error in case the Prefix value is empty in the component?

Comment: It won't give an error when testing, no. When sending a Mailing you can choose, by way of the "Only send e-mail to Contacts with all required Merge Field data" checkbox. That way, if someone doesn't have the data it won't send an e-mail with missing words in them.

Comment: But, the requirement is to send an email, even if Prefix is missing for a particular contact. In that case, how should I check it?

Comment: In that case you just leave the checkbox unchecked.